# Two dimensional array pointer notation works for one version but not the other...I think

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

When I used the following function definition for a 32 bit version everything worked fine:

```
void intensifyPixel(int x, int y, double distance, unsigned long *grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth], unsigned long color){
    unsigned long intensity; 
    //assign intensity returned from filter function 
    intensity = filter ((floor(fabs (distance)) + .5), color);
    //write intensity value to x,y coordinates of framebuffer memory    
    *( *(grid + y) + x) = intensity;
}
```

Now I am trying to implement a 16 bit version using the same code except unsigned short instead of unsigned long for the array

```
void intensifyPixel(int x, int y, double distance, unsigned short *grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth], unsigned short color){
    unsigned short intensity; 
    //assign intensity returned from filter function 
    intensity = filter ((floor(fabs (distance)) + .5), color);
    //write intensity value to x,y coordinates of framebuffer memory    
    *( *(grid + y) + x) = intensity;
}
```

I've changed the return type of the filter function accordingly.

Here is a link to the code that works (32 bit version): http://codepad.org/GsK00pd5

Here is a link to the code that does not work properly (16 bit version: http://codepad.org/6eAeTful

There is a lot there. It's really hard for me to narrow this problem down, and I apologize for that.

I hope one of you can see what I cannot.

It may be worth mentioning that the point here is to pass a pointer to a two dimensional array to the intensifyPixel function.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Like I said in the other answer, just pass in `unsigned short **grid`...I don't understand why you want to pass in `unsigned short *grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth]`. If it's for more convenient indexing, well, `grid[y][x]` isn't so bad.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler need to know the number of columns in a two dimensional array? I tried what you suggested and I got an error. I think you can access the code and apply what you are suggesting through the link to my code. If your solution works please do post it. Thank you for any assistance (and hand holding) you can provide

Comment: I just tried it again to be sure and I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, this depends on what `grid` actually is! Is it a pointer to a contiguous 2D array, or a pointer to an array of row pointers? In the former case, it's really a pointer to 1D array with special indexing (thus you use `(*grid)[y*framebufferwidth + x]`); in the latter case it's a 'normal' dynamic 2D array with row pointers (thus you use `grid[y][x]`).

Answer (score 2):

Defined as a parameter `unsigned long *grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth]`, `grid` **IS NOT**

an **array** of `framebufferheight` arrays of `framebufferwidth` pointers to `unsigned long`, **IT IS**

a **pointer** to an array of `framebufferwidth` pointers to `unsigned long`.

That is because, in C, arrays are never passed as parameters in their entirety. Instead of an array being passed, the pointer to its first element is passed, despite the syntax and what not. Look again at what I said `grid` is and is not. That's the essence.

Now, `*( *(grid + y) + x)` or, equivalently, `grid[y][x]` resolves to a pointer to `unsigned long`.

Assigning an integer to a pointer is unlikely what you want.

You probably want to redefine the `grid` parameter this way:

```
unsigned long grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth]
```

or this way equivalently:

```
unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth]
```

so `grid[y][x]` would resolve to `unsigned long` and not a pointer to one.

The frame buffer outside of the function can be allocated either statically:

```
// 2-d array of unsigned longs
unsigned long grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth];
```

Or dynamically:

```
// pointer to an array of framebufferwidth unsigned longs
unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * framebufferheight * framebufferwidth);
```

You pass it as is to `intensifyPixel()`: `intensifyPixel(..., grid, ...)` and access in the same manner: `grid[y][x] = something;`

**UPDATE**: If despite all my attempts to explain it you still don't get it right or are forgetting something, see a more complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define framebufferheight 20
#define framebufferwidth  64

void visualize(unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth])
{
  int y, x;
  for (y = 0; y < framebufferheight; y++)
  {
    for (x = 0; x < framebufferwidth; x++)
      printf("%c", (char)grid[y][x]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void drawBox(unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth],
             int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, char c)
{
  int y, x;
  for (y = y1; y <= y2 ; y++)
    for (x = x1; x <= x2; x++)
      grid[y][x] = c;
}

void clear(unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth], char c)
{
  drawBox(grid, 0, 0, framebufferwidth - 1, framebufferheight - 1, c);
}

int main(void)
{
  {
    unsigned long (*grid)[framebufferwidth] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned long) * framebufferheight * framebufferwidth);
    clear(grid, '.');
    drawBox(grid, 1, 1, 10, 5, '1');
    drawBox(grid, 40, 10, 55, 18, '2');
    grid[framebufferheight / 2][framebufferwidth / 2] = '+';
    visualize(grid);
  }

  {
    unsigned long grid[framebufferheight][framebufferwidth];
    clear(grid, ',');
    drawBox(grid, 1, 1, 10, 5, 'a');
    drawBox(grid, 40, 10, 55, 18, 'b');
    grid[framebufferheight / 2][framebufferwidth / 2] = '*';
    visualize(grid);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/QOkw6)):

```
................................................................
.1111111111.....................................................
.1111111111.....................................................
.1111111111.....................................................
.1111111111.....................................................
.1111111111.....................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................................................
................................+.......2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
........................................2222222222222222........
................................................................
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,aaaaaaaaaa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,aaaaaaaaaa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,aaaaaaaaaa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,aaaaaaaaaa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,aaaaaaaaaa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Thank you for your insight. The problem I am experiencing is that grid is only being written to in a spotty and incorrect manner, and the only issue I can see is that it would be a problem with the array notation. I have implemented what you suggested and I am still getting the spotty output where it should be consistent. Some iterations do not result in writing to grid, and I do not know why.

Comment: Why people choose a crappy obsolete language like C to write anything other than operating systems is beyond me.

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: Sure thing. Look at all the pain these poor folks asking these questions go through, needlessly. And yet there are still CS instructors teaching C as a beginning programming language ... that's incompetent.

Comment: @JimBalter At least it's not C++. But I think there should be a better place for such discussions than SO. Perhaps, programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: You speak from ignorance. While I have been quite critical of C++, C++11 is a modern programming language. People who think C is a good programming language, by itself or in comparison to C++, are not competent software professionals. (And I certainly include Linus.) That's all I have to say here.

Comment: @JimBalter Your opinion matters to me. Not.